# Why use STL/C++ style casting when you can use simple C style casting

Tags: c++

I don’t know whether to use the STL casting options (static_cast, reinterpret_cast, dynamic_cast), or just simply use old-fashioned C style casting. I’ve read and watched many things about this, and most of ‘em say that C++ style casting is mostly syntax-sugar.

Is it really necessary to use C++ style casting, does it offer better performance or safety? Or is it less of a hassle to use standard C casting?

Comment: FYI: C++ casts have nothing to do with "STL".

Comment: A C-style cast is an extremely heavy sledgehammer. If you try to use it you'll hurt yourself.